# django serialize exclude primary key for some reason

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

My model is as following:

```
class PolicyRule(models.Model):
    uid = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    maxAmount = models.FloatField()
    destinations = models.TextField()
```

and for some reason, the following code

```
rules_list = PolicyRule.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(rules_list, 5)
rules = paginator.page(page)
rules_json = serialize('json', list(rules))
```

produces this output

`"[{\"model\": \"webapp.policyrule\", \"pk\": 1576966788, \"fields\": {\"maxAmount\": 50.0, \"destinations\": \"ronen\"}}]"`

which is without the UID field! why is this happening?

Comment: have you tried to change the name of "uid" field?

Comment: Is the uid field coming out as pk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the field **`uid`** as [**Primary Key**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) by using **`primary_key=True`** which is represented as **`pk`** in the output JSON.
 ie, the value ***`"pk": 1576966788`*** is representing the value of **`uid`** field

---

It's not possible to include the **`uid`** field inside the ***`fields`***. If you want more customization over the data, use [**DRF Serializers**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) of [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)